# Paper cone paint strainer for latex paint

Tags: paint

I'm trying to strain some run-of-the-mill latex paint that has rust from the can, etc. I have used filters like the one shown below in 100 micron and 190 micron, and both clog almost immediately (with paint, not debris). It seems like they make 400 micron strainer bags for 5 gallon buckets, but I haven't been able to find anything bigger than 190 micron in this paper cone style. Is there is a different product usually used to strain small quantities (gallon and quart)? How do you do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Throw out the rusty paint, move on with life.
2. Get a colander from a thrift store.
3. Buy the "5 gallon" filter and set that over your ring so that you
   can use just part of it (perhaps with some clothespins to hold it in
   place.)
4. (non-ripped) nylon stocking. Or non-ripped portion of ripped nylon stocking.

Comment: Point #1. I'm always amazed at the length people will go through to "save" a buck. The time & money spent trying to rehabilitate some "run-of-the-mill" paint will end up being more than buying a new gallon. If it was some sort of high-end $100/gallon specialty paint, it might be worth it.